# Postgresql: Grouping with limit on group size using window functions

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Is there a way in Postgresql to write a query which groups rows based on a column with a limit without discarding additional rows.

Say I've got a table with three columns `id, color, score` with the following rows

```
1 red 10.0
2 red 7.0
3 red 3.0
4 blue 5.0
5 green 4.0
6 blue 2.0
7 blue 1.0
```

I can get a grouping based on color with window functions with the following query

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, color, score, rank()
    OVER (PARTITION BY color ORDER BY score DESC)
    FROM grouping_test
) AS foo WHERE rank <= 2;
```

with the result

```
  id | color | score | rank 
 ----+-------+-------+------
   4 | blue  |   5.0 |    1
   6 | blue  |   2.0 |    2
   5 | green |   4.0 |    1
   1 | red   |  10.0 |    1
   2 | red   |   7.0 |    2
```

which discards item with ranks > 2. However what I need is a result like

```
1 red 10.0
2 red 7.0
4 blue 5.0
6 blue 2.0
5 green 4.0
3 red 3.0
7 blue 1.0
```

With no discarded rows.

**Edit:**
To be more precise about the logic I need:

1. Get me the row with the highest score
2. The next row with the same color and the highest possible score
3. The item with the highest score of the remaining items
4. Same as 2., but for the row from 3.
   ...

Continue as long as pairs with the same color can be found, then order whats left by descending score.

The import statements for a test table can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bbcfc/95).
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the order logic exactly? You want the colours to be grouped based on the lowest id for the colour?

Comment: The query in your question was the exact thing I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using two nested window functions

```
SELECT
  id
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    color,
    score,
    ((rank() OVER color_window) - 1) / 2 AS rank_window_id
  FROM grouping_test
  WINDOW color_window AS (PARTITION BY color ORDER BY score DESC)
) as foo
WINDOW rank_window AS (PARTITION BY (color, rank_window_id))
ORDER BY
  (max(score) OVER rank_window) DESC,
  color;
```

With `2` being the parameter of the group size.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `ORDER BY (rank <= 2) DESC` to get the rows with rank<=2 above all else:

```
SELECT id,color,score FROM (
SELECT id, color, score, rank()
OVER (PARTITION BY color ORDER BY score DESC),
max(score) OVER (PARTITION BY color) mx
FROM grouping_test
) AS foo 
ORDER BY 
  (rank <= 2) DESC, 
  CASE WHEN rank<=2 THEN mx ELSE NULL END DESC,
  id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bbcfc/109

Comment: I edited the questions to be more precise about the order logic I need. Hope to be more clear this time.

Comment: @MarioKonschake I updated. Though not that I look at the query above it seems it's almost the same solution.