# PostgreSQL find top N rows grouped by date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a typical blog app and have a view that returns the following data:

```
| post_id | title | publish_on | tag_id | tag_name |

| 1 | Why is Postgres awesome                | 2014-09-02 | 1    | tech |
| 1 | Why is Postgres awesome                | 2014-09-02 | 2    | postgres |
| 2 | How to ask a question on stackoverflow | 2014-09-10 | 1    | tech |
| 2 | How to ask a question on stackoverflow | 2014-09-10 | 2    | postgres |
| 2 | How to ask a question on stackoverflow | 2014-09-10 | 3    | guide |
| 3 | This is a draft                        | null       | null | null |
| 4 | This is something else without a tag   | 2014-10-10 | null | null |
| 5 | This question is also published on 9/2 | 2014-09-02 | null | null |
| 6 | And so is this                         | 2014-09-02 | 1    | tech |
| 7 | But this one is on 9/10                | 2014-09-10 | 3    | guide|
| 8 | This is on 10/10                       | 2014-10-10 | null | null |
| 9 | And so is this                         | 2014-10-10 | 2    | postgres |
| 10| This is another draft                  | null       | null | null |
```

I'm looking to group the posts by publish_on date and then select the top 3 posts for each bucket(this will be presented in the dashboard so that the user can know what posts will be published today, sometime next week and later) Now I've tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167434/postgresql-grouping-with-limit-on-group-size-using-window-functions) which use something like:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY publish_on ORDER BY publish_on DESC)
```

but since rows can be duplicated due to multiple tags, those queries fail. I've also tried a combination of various `PARTION BY` criteria, but I guess I don't understand them well enough to get it working.

Any help/pointers appreciated!

**Update: Expected Output**

For each publish_on date, I want to get N (3) posts expected to be published on that date.

```
| 1 | Why is Postgres awesome                | 2014-09-02 | 1    | tech |
| 1 | Why is Postgres awesome                | 2014-09-02 | 2    | postgres |
| 5 | This question is also published on 9/2 | 2014-09-02 | null | null |
| 6 | And so is this                         | 2014-09-02 | 1    | tech |

| 2 | How to ask a question on stackoverflow | 2014-09-10 | 1    | tech |
| 2 | How to ask a question on stackoverflow | 2014-09-10 | 2    | postgres |
| 2 | How to ask a question on stackoverflow | 2014-09-10 | 3    | guide |
| 7 | But this one is on 9/10                | 2014-09-10 | 3    | guide|

| 4 | This is something else without a tag   | 2014-10-10 | null | null |
| 8 | This is on 10/10                       | 2014-10-10 | null | null |
| 9 | And so is this                         | 2014-10-10 | 2    | postgres |

| 3 | This is a draft                        | null       | null | null |
| 10| This is another draft                  | null       | null | null |
```

Hope this makes the question a little more clear to understand.

Comment: are tag_id and tag_name related? I assume so, but tag_id has the related tag_name 'postgres' and 'guide'.

Comment: @simo.3792095 sorry, they are related. Will update the table to reflect that. Thanks!

Comment: I assume post_id's 4, 8 & 10 will appear grouped on the 10th of october. You currently show post_id 4 under 10th of September.

Comment: Arrgh, you're right 4, 8, 9 should be grouped separately!

Comment: yes 4,8 & 9 - not 4, 8 & 10 as I said. ;-0

Comment: If you post scripts to create table and fill data it would be easier to test solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/82c00/1)

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tag_name order by publish_on DESC) AS r,
    t.*
    from blog t ) x
where x.r <= 3
```

**Explanation and questions**:

I assume by "each bucket" you mean tag_name (or tag_id).  Then you only want the 3 most recent post within "each bucket".  If a post is tagged multiple times, then how do you want to treat them - appear once per tag - or appear only once per result set?

**EDIT**

This now displays the results as you expect. [SQL Fiddle for this here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/7fae5/6)

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.Post_id, y.title, x.Publish_on, y.tag_id, y.tag_name
FROM blog y
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY publish_on order by publish_on DESC) AS r,
    t.post_id, t.publish_on
    from (SELECT DISTINCT s.post_id, s.publish_on
          FROM blog s) t 
           ) x ON x.post_id = y.post_id
where x.r <= 3
ORDER BY x.publish_on
```

The main problem that is adding to your complexity, is that the table structure is not normalised.  This should in fact be 3 tables, so that the descriptions and date will not be duplicated in different rows, ie

```
CREATE TABLE blog
(post_id int not null,
 title varchar(50) not null,
 publish_on date)

CREATE TABLE blog_tag
(post_id int not null,
 tag_ig int not null)

CREATE TABLE tag
(tag_id int not null,
 tag_name varchar(10) not null)
```

Then the SQL can be replaced with [see full SQL Fidle for this here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/61166/4)

```
SELECT x.Post_id, x.title, x.Publish_on, t.tag_id, t.tag_name
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY publish_on order by publish_on DESC) AS r,
    b.*
    from blog b) x
LEFT JOIN blog_tag bt ON bt.post_id = x.post_id
LEFT JOIN tag t ON t.tag_id = bt.tag_id
WHERE x.r <= 3
ORDER BY x.publish_on, x.post_id, t.tag_id
```

Comment: I've updated the question with expected output. By bucket I meant "grouping of date". Can you take another look at the question?

Comment: Works great! The tables are actually normalized, and the sample data comes from a view. Both options you posted work, but since I have control over the view, I'm going to modify it accordingly to use option number 2. Thanks!